# Practicing arrays with String class methods

Tags: java, strings, array, reinventing-the-wheel

I am a Spanish programming teacher in a vocational training course and we are studying arrays. In order to practice and to get the students familiarized with some methods of the `String` class, I proposed them to reinvent the wheel, implementing some methods of the `String` class using `char` arrays.

This is the solution that I will provide to my students. The lack of comments is because the solution will be explained in class.

```
package es.programacion1k.arrays;

import java.util.Arrays;

//Using char arrays from strings with the String.toCharArray () function implement the following methods
//length
//indexOf
//charAt(index)
//lastIndexOf(ch);
//replace(oldChar, newChar)
//substring(beginIndex, endIndex)
//substring(beginIndex)
//equals(anObject)
//trim();
//concat(str)
//endsWith(suffix)
//contains(s)
//indexOf(str)
//split("-");

public class MyStringMethods {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String empty = "";
    String ordinary = "Ordinary Test String";

    System.out.printf("String Class Method - String: \"%s\" Length: %d%n", empty, empty.length());
    System.out.printf("String Class Method - String: \"%s\" Length: %d%n", ordinary, ordinary.length());
    System.out.printf("myMethod            - String: \"%s\" Length: %d%n", empty, myLength(empty));
    System.out.printf("myMethod            - String: \"%s\" Length: %d%n", ordinary, myLength(ordinary));

    char characterToFind = 'N';
    String template = "indexOf   - String: \"%s\" character: %c position: %d%n";
    String myTemplate = "myIndexOf - String: \"%s\" character: %c position: %d%n";
    System.out.printf(template, empty, characterToFind, empty.indexOf(characterToFind));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, empty, characterToFind, myIndexOf(empty, characterToFind));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, characterToFind, ordinary.indexOf(characterToFind));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, characterToFind, myIndexOf(ordinary, characterToFind));

    int position = 14;
    template = "charAt - String: \"%s\" position: %d character: %c%n";
    myTemplate = "myCharAt - String: \"%s\" position: %d character: %c%n";
    // System.out.printf(plantilla,StringVacia,position,StringVacia.charAt(position));
    // System.out.printf(myPlantilla,StringVacia,position,myCharAt(StringVacia,position));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, position, ordinary.charAt(position));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, position, myCharAt(ordinary, position));

    characterToFind = 'e';
    template = "lastIndexOf   - String: \"%s\" character: %c position: %d%n";
    myTemplate = "myLastIndexOf - String: \"%s\" character: %c position: %d%n";
    System.out.printf(template, empty, characterToFind, empty.lastIndexOf(characterToFind));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, empty, characterToFind, myLastIndexOf(empty, characterToFind));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, characterToFind, ordinary.lastIndexOf(characterToFind));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, characterToFind, myLastIndexOf(ordinary, characterToFind));

    char characterBefore = 'e';
    char characterAfter = 'E';
    template = "replace   - String: \"%s\" characterBefore: %c characterAfter: %c StringAfter: \"%s\"%n";
    myTemplate = "myReplace - String: \"%s\" characterBefore: %c characterAfter: %c StringAfter: \"%s\"%n";
    System.out.printf(template, empty, characterBefore, characterAfter,
            empty.replace(characterBefore, characterAfter));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, empty, characterBefore, characterAfter,
            myReplace(empty, characterBefore, characterAfter));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, characterBefore, characterAfter,
            ordinary.replace(characterBefore, characterAfter));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, characterBefore, characterAfter,
            myReplace(ordinary, characterBefore, characterAfter));

    int startPosition = 4;
    int endPosition = 13;
    template = "subString(start,end) - String: \"%s\" start: %d end: %d Result: %s%n";
    myTemplate = "mySubString(start,end) - String: \"%s\" start: %d end: %d Result: %s%n";
    // System.out.printf(plantilla,vacia,positionInicial,positionFinal,vacia.substring(positionInicial,
    // positionFinal));
    // System.out.printf(myPlantilla,vacia,positionInicial,positionFinal,mySubstring(vacia,positionInicial,
    // positionFinal));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, startPosition, endPosition,
            ordinary.substring(startPosition, endPosition));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, startPosition, endPosition,
            mySubstring(ordinary, startPosition, endPosition));

    startPosition = 4;
    template = "subString(start) - String: \"%s\" start: %d Result: %s%n";
    myTemplate = "mySubString(start) - String: \"%s\" start: %d Result: %s%n";
    // System.out.printf(plantilla,vacia,positionInicial,vacia.substring(positionInicial));
    // System.out.printf(myPlantilla,vacia,positionInicial,mySubstring(vacia,positionInicial));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, startPosition, ordinary.substring(startPosition));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, startPosition, mySubstring(ordinary, startPosition));

    String second = "Ordinary Test String";
    template = "equals(str) - String: \"%s\" Second String: \"%s\" Result: %b%n";
    myTemplate = "myEquals(str) - String: \"%s\" Second String: \"%s\" Result: %b%n";
    System.out.printf(template, empty, second, empty.equals(second));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, empty, second, myEquals(empty, second));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, second, ordinary.equals(second));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, second, myEquals(ordinary, second));

    String withWhiteSpaces = "  Test     ";
    template = "trim() - String: \"%s\" Resultado: \"%s\"%n";
    myTemplate = "myTrim() - String: \"%s\" Resultado: \"%s\"%n";
    System.out.printf(template, empty, empty.trim());
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, empty, myTrim(empty));
    System.out.printf(template, withWhiteSpaces, withWhiteSpaces.trim());
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, withWhiteSpaces, myTrim(withWhiteSpaces));

    String added = " more characters";
    template = "concat(str) - String: \"%s\" Added: \"%s\" Result: \"%s\"%n";
    myTemplate = "myConcat(str) - String: \"%s\" Added: \"%s\" Result: \"%s\"%n";
    System.out.printf(template, empty, added, empty.concat(added));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, empty, added, myConcat(empty, added));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, added, ordinary.concat(added));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, added, myConcat(ordinary, added));

    String ending = "String";
    template = "endsWith(str) - String: \"%s\" ending: \"%s\" Result: \"%b\"%n";
    myTemplate = "myEndsWith(str) - String: \"%s\" ending: \"%s\" Result: \"%b\"%n";
    System.out.printf(template, empty, ending, empty.endsWith(ending));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, empty, ending, myEndsWith(empty, ending));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, ending, ordinary.endsWith(ending));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, ending, myEndsWith(ordinary, ending));

    String toFind = "String";
    template = "indexOf(str) - String: \"%s\" tofind: \"%s\" Result: \"%d\"%n";
    myTemplate = "myIndexOf(str) - String: \"%s\" tofind: \"%s\" Result: \"%d\"%n";
    System.out.printf(template, empty, toFind, empty.indexOf(toFind));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, empty, toFind, myIndexOf(empty,toFind));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, toFind, ordinary.indexOf(toFind));
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, toFind, myIndexOf(ordinary,toFind));

    String separator = "o";
    template = "split   - String: \"%s\" character: %s%n";
    myTemplate = "mySplit - String: \"%s\" character: %s%n";
//      System.out.printf(plantilla, vacia, separador, vacia.split(separador));
//      System.out.printf(myPlantilla, vacia, characterBuscado, myIndexOf(vacia, characterBuscado));
    System.out.printf(template, ordinary, separator);

    for(String s:ordinary.split(separator)){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.printf(myTemplate, ordinary, separator);
    for(String s:mySplit(ordinary,separator)){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

static int myLength(String s) {
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    return characters.length;
}

static int myIndexOf(String s, char c) {
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if (characters[i] == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

static int myCharAt(String s, int pos) {
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    return characters[pos];

}

static int myLastIndexOf(String s, char c) {
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = characters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (characters[i] == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

static String myReplace(String s, char before, char after) {
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (characters[i] == before) {
            characters[i] = after;
        }
    }

    return new String(characters);
}

private static String mySubstring(String s, int initialPosition, int finalPosition) {
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    int lengthSubString = finalPosition - initialPosition;
    char[] result = new char[lengthSubString];
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthSubString; i++) {
        result[i] = characters[i + initialPosition];
    }

    return new String(result);
}

private static String mySubstring(String String, int positionInicial) {
    return mySubstring(String, positionInicial, String.length());
}

static boolean myEquals(String first, String second) {
    char[] charactersFirst = first.toCharArray();
    char[] charactersSecond = second.toCharArray();
    if (charactersFirst.length != charactersSecond.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < charactersFirst.length; i++) {
        if (charactersFirst[i] != charactersSecond[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

static String myTrim(String s) {
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    if (characters.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    int initialWhiteSpaces = 0;
    while (Character.isWhitespace(characters[initialWhiteSpaces])) {
        initialWhiteSpaces++;
    }
    int finalWhiteSpaces = characters.length - 1;
    while (Character.isWhitespace(characters[finalWhiteSpaces])) {
        finalWhiteSpaces--;
    }

    return mySubstring(s, initialWhiteSpaces, finalWhiteSpaces + 1);
}

static String myConcat(String s, String added) {
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    char[] charactersAdded = added.toCharArray();

    char[] result = new char[characters.length + charactersAdded.length];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        result[i] = characters[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < charactersAdded.length; j++) {
        result[i + j] = charactersAdded[j];
    }
    return new String(result);
}

static boolean myEndsWith(String s,String ending){
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    char[] endingCharacters = ending.toCharArray();
    if(characters.length<endingCharacters.length){
        return false;
    }

    for(int i=characters.length-1,j=endingCharacters.length-1;j>=0;j--,i--){
        if(characters[i]!=endingCharacters[j]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
static int myIndexOf(String s,String toFind){
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    char[] charactersToFind = toFind.toCharArray();
    if(characters.length<charactersToFind.length){
        return -1;
    }
    int lookingAtPosition=0;
    do{
//          System.out.println("myrando: "+characters[positionmyrada]);
        int iguales=0;
        int i=lookingAtPosition;
        int j=0;
        while(j<charactersToFind.length){
//              System.out.print("entro "+i+" "+j);
            if(characters[i]!=charactersToFind[j]){
                break;
            }
            i++;
            j++;

        }
        if(j==charactersToFind.length){
//              System.out.println("Encontrado en: "+positionmyrada);
            return lookingAtPosition;
        }

        lookingAtPosition++;
    }while(lookingAtPosition<=characters.length-charactersToFind.length);
    return -1;
}
static boolean myContains(String s,String toFind){
    return myIndexOf(s,toFind)!=-1;
}
static String[] mySplit(String s,String splitter){

    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    char separator=splitter.charAt(0);
    int tokens=1;
    for(int i=0;i<characters.length-1;i++){
        if(characters[i]==separator){
            tokens++;
        }
    }
    char[][] result=new char[s.length()][];

    int indexString = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens; i++) {
        int indexSubString = 0;

        while (characters[indexString] != separator) {
            if (indexString == characters.length - 1) {
                indexSubString++;
                break;
            }
            indexString++;
            indexSubString++;
        }
        result[i]=new char[indexSubString];
        indexString++;

    }


    indexString = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens; i++) {
        int indiceSubString = 0;

        while (characters[indexString] != separator) {
            result[i][indiceSubString] = characters[indexString];
            if (indexString == characters.length - 1) {
                break;
            }
            indexString++;
            indiceSubString++;
        }

        indexString++;

    }

    String[] finalResult=new String[tokens];
    for(int i=0;i<tokens;i++){
        finalResult[i]=new String(result[i]);
    }
    return finalResult;
    }

}
```

The `split` function (with a character as a separator) is really difficult to implement and I do not ask the students to do it, it's just an example.

We have only studied what is used in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Object-oriented

The first comment, is that all of the methods are `static`, and their names begin with `my...`. Java is an object-oriented language, so in order to re-implement a `String` class working on character arrays, it would be preferable to create a new `MyString` class. On that class, you can then have the typical methods `length()` or `trim()`, with a clear name (instead of having them prefixed with `my`).

Consider having the starting template of:

```
public class MyString {

    private char[] characters;

    public MyString(String str) {
        characters = str.toCharArray();
    }

    public int length() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Then the rest of the code can operate on the character array alone, without interference from a `String` parameter to a static method. The big advantage with this approach is that you gain

#### Unit testing

Right now, all of the test code is written inside the `main` method. While this can work during development to easily test some scenarios, having a proper unit test, written with JUnit or TestNG for example, is preferable: you can create this test class on your side, and verify automatically the all of the students submissions with it.

A simple JUnit test would be

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyStringTest {

    @Test
    public int testLengthOfEmptyString() {
        MyString str = new MyString("");
        assertEquals(0, str.length());
    }

    // more tests (one with a non empty string for example)

}
```

#### The methods

The currently all follow the pattern of fetching the character array from the given String parameter. When refactoring this to the `MyString` class having a character array field, this is simplified. Instead of

> ```
> static int myLength(String s) {
>     char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
>     return characters.length;
> }
> ```

you can directly have

```
public int length() {
    return characters.length;
}
```

Keep in mind that the methods differ slightly from the ones of the `String` class (`charAt` method [returns a `char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) instead of an `int`, or `indexOf` takes an `int` as parameter [instead of a `char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-), etc.), although it may not matter since the point is to learn arrays. I also noticed that some of them are `private` (like `mySubstring`); was that the intent? They should probably be made public and to be implemented by the student.

Be careful with the implementation of `trim()`, it does not have the same behaviour as `String.trim()`. For example, consider the following String having a [paragraph separator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm) (e.g. `\u2029`), and a tabulation character (to see the difference):

```
System.out.println("\u2029\tABAB".trim());  // prints "    ABAB"
System.out.println(myTrim("\u2029\tABAB")); // prints "ABAB"
```

This is because the rewritten `trim()` removes all Java white space characters as returned by [`isWhitespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-), but the `trim()` built-in considers all characters below `' '`.

A note regarding `split` as well: currently it fails if it is passed an empty String. That case should be taken care of: it could be by returning an array of all the characters, like the built-in `split` does, but the intent for this method is more to accept a `char separator` as parameter, instead of a String, because what it does is split by a single character.

The method `split` can be implemented in a more direct way, still reasoning on the character arrays: step 1 is to calculate the total number of tokens and step 2 is to loop over the characters, keeping the running index where a character equal to the separator is found (starting at 0) and taking the substring between that index and the next one (I used `Arrays.copyOfRange` in the snippet below, but that can easily be replaced with a for loop if you wish to keep it strictly without utility methods).

```
public String[] split(char separator) {
    int length = characters.length;
    int tokens = 0;
    for (char ch : characters) {
        if (ch == separator) {
            tokens++;
        }
    }

    String[] result = new String[tokens + 1];
    int resultIndex = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (characters[i] == separator) {
            result[resultIndex] = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(characters, startIndex, i));
            startIndex = i + 1; // + 1 to skip the separator
            resultIndex++;
        }
    }
    // to take the last part into account
    result[resultIndex] = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(characters, startIndex, length));

    return result;
}
```

The rest of the code is fine; just make sure to remove the unused variable (`int iguales = 0;`) and commented-out code in `indexOf(toFind)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your appropiate comment. It was really helpful